# Requesting product info without actually starting the payment process

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I've implemented in-app purchases for my app, but to comply with Apple guidelines I need to format and display the localized currency of the product in my stores UI. When the user clicks to display store UI, I create a `productsRequest` to request and show info for the according product. The problem is that it also starts the purchase process for the purchase I have set up. All I want it do is display the formatted currency in a label, without starting the purchase process.

Button for displaying store UI:

```
-(void)openIAP
{
        if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
            NSLog(@"User can make payments");
            SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier, nil]];
            productsRequest.delegate = self;
            [productsRequest start];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"User can't make payments, don't open store");
        }
}
```

productsRequest

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *validProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Products Available!");
        _numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [_numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [_numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [_numberFormatter setLocale:validProduct.priceLocale];
        NSString *formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:validProduct.price];
        NSLog(@"The price is %@", formattedPrice);
        [adsPrice setString:formattedPrice];
        [self purchase:validProduct]; //this needs to be moved
    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
        //this is called if your product id is not valid, this shouldn't be called unless that happens.
    }
}
```

I understand how this method works, but I don't know what to do with the `[self purchase:validProduct]`. I tried to create and call another `SKProductsRequest` method called `justProductsRequest` with different parameter names. It had the same code as `productsRequest` (as shown above) just without `[self purchase:validProduct];` but it still called `productsRequest` instead of `justProductsRequest`.

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a product request to initiate a purchase. The product request provides product information such as price which you can then use to update your app's UI.

When you receive `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:`, you should store the array of products that you receive. This contains all of the SKProduct items that you need to create an SKPayment object. Additionally, you should update your UI to show the price of your IAP items here (as you seem to be doing). You should only need to make this request once.

When you want to start the purchase flow (e.g. when a user presses a button for an IAP item), find the relevant product by its identifier in the array of products that you stored before, and use `[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:]` to create the payment object.

The [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) provides lots of great information. The correct purchase process that I have described can be seen in "Figure I-1" on the page that I linked to.